# How to sort json in reverse alphabetical order using gulp-json-sort plugin

Tags: json, gulp

With [gulp-json-sort](https://github.com/jwbay/gulp-json-sort) I was able to sort a JSON file in alphabetical order. But I don't understand how to use its API to sort in reverse alphabetical order. I tried the following with no avail, it's still sorting in alphabetical order as if I weren't using any function inside sortJSON():

```
sortJSON({
  function (a, b) {
    return a.key < b.key ? 1 : -1;
}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, according to their API I had to use it as follows:

```
sortJSON({
  cmp: function (a, b) {
    return a.key < b.key ? 1 : -1;
}})
```

It'd have been better if the README of the plugin provided an example! :)